# Pyinstaller import error no module named path

Tags: python, import, module

I am trying to build a program in python that uses a lot of different modules.When i run it normally (from cmd) everything works fine, but when i try to create an executable doesnt work. I have tried using py2exe and pyinstaller,tried googling the problem for a couple of hours but nothing really works. I am getting this when i run the exe from cmd. I have tried manually importing the necessary modules but still didnt work.  Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 35, in <module>

File "site-packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 39, in init

  File "site-packages\pyttsx\engine.py", line 45, in __init__

  File "site-packages\pyttsx\driver.py", line 66, in __init__

  File "site-packages\pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.py", line 37, in buildDriver

  File "site-packages\pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.py", line 46, in __init__

  File "site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 309, in WithEvents

  File "site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 524, in EnsureModule

  File "site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 291, in 
MakeModuleForTypelib

  File "site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py", line 286, in 
GenerateFromTypeLibSpec

  File "site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 554, in 
AddModuleToCache

  File "site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 633, in _GetModule

  File "c:\users\giorgo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmppddzle\gen_py\C866CA3A-32F7-
11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4.py", line 10, in <module>

    import win32com.client.CLSIDToClass, pythoncom, pywintypes

  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 158, in load_module

    return self._importer.load_module(fullname, self._fullname)


  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 389, in load_module

    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

  File "site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>

  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 158, in load_module

    return self._importer.load_module(fullname, self._fullname)

  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 389, in load_module

    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

  File "site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 2, in <module>



  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 158, in load_module

    return self._importer.load_module(fullname, self._fullname)

  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", 
line 389, in load_module

    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

  File "os.py", line 120, in <module>

ImportError: No module named path

alltogether returned -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem. There seems to be a bug in setuptools 19.3. Downgrading to setuptools 19.2 fixed it for me.

To downgrade using pip simply type:

```
pip install setuptools==19.2
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: didnt work...same error again. Thanks for the reply tho...really appreciate it.